# How can I override "display:inline-block" with "display: block" in IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Here's some code to illustrate the problem I'm running into. *[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mmpX3/)*

```
<div class="normal">
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">Test longer</a>
</div>
<div class="ib blockbyclass">
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">Test longer</a>
</div>
<div class="ib">
    <a href="#" style="display: block;">Test</a>
    <a href="#" style="display: block;">Test longer</a>
</div>
```

```css
body{background-color: gray;}
div{float:left; margin: 5px;}
a {background-color: black; color: white;}
div.ib a {display: inline-block;}
div.normal > a {display: block;}
div.blockbyclass> a {display: block; }
```

I have a certain type of link that under most circumstances needs to be rendered as inline-block, but in a certain case needs to be rendered as block elements. Specifically, I want them to each appear on their own line and take up the entire area of the containing div. In this particular case, the `div` containing the links is set to float, so it will resize itself based on the largest of the links inside it. IE8, IE9, Firefox and Chrome render these links correctly, but no matter what I do IE7 refuses to forget the `display: inline-block` rule.

How can I make IE7 show these elements in "block" mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a `hasLayout` trigger by the `inline-block` setting. To quote http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html (my emphasis added):

"The display-property differs: while 'inline-block' sets haslayout = true, **the flag will not be reset to false later on by overriding the value with 'block' or 'inline' in another rule set.**"

This is unlike most `hasLayout` triggers that can be reset. Therefore, I think to fix your problem, you need to think in reverse. You need to have `block` be your default for the `a` tag and then add a class to get your `inline-block` when you need it.

Sort of like http://jsfiddle.net/mmpX3/33/ where `blockbyclass` I replaced with `inlinebyclass` (which is really `inline-block`).

**Updated Explanation:** You probably noticed that when you switched to `block` after going from `inline-block` that it "sort of worked" (the lines of text still move down). That is because it is displaying as a block, but one that `hasLayout` as opposed to one that does not. I don't know your particular situation, but *if you can set* a `width` on the containing `div` then a secondary solution to that I proposed above of "thinking in reverse" is to then set a `width: 100%` in conjunction with your "resetting" to `block`, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/mmpX3/64/.

**Updated Caution:** I don't know if you have other css you plan to apply to the `a` tags, but if any of that triggers `hasLayout` then you will need to watch out for that (and perhaps find a different method). See for example this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mmpX3/69/ in which everything is set to `block` but because I put a `min-height` on the `a` tag, it still has the same issues as your original problem.

Comment: +1. I was hoping to avoid this approach, since I'm generating the `ib`-style buttons with a utility class and there's a lot of other stuff going on there. Avoiding applying the `inline-block`-generating class will require some hokey code, but it's looking like it may end up being the only way to get things to look the way I want them to.

Comment: Can you not keep all the code associated with the `ib` class in a `baseButton` class (or some such) and apply a second class `ib` as standard *except* in the case when you don't want it, in which case you still apply any other necessary changes for `block` display via `blockbyclass`? The point is to *avoid* setting `inline-block` (for IE7 anyway) *in the css cascade* unless actually desired. If you work with 3 classes, 1 for base styles, 1 for `inline-block` itself, and 1 for `block` then you avoid every setting `inline-block` unless you are actually using it.

Comment: I marked this as the answer, but gave the bounty to Galled (http://stackoverflow.com/q/8205404/120955). See his answer for an explanation. Thank you for all your time.

Comment: Well, I can't say I'm not slightly disappointed. However, I'm glad my info helped you in solving your issue. That is what the site is all about.

Answer (score 4):

**Update: moved from comments here:**

The problem is on `div` floating. When you float an element, that will be outside of pages normal stream, so, `IE` will take for it `width:0; height:0;` and when you put some elements in it, they will create their own `height` and `width` and the floated-element will be rendered how can push them *(my English is really bad, so sorry)*. First step, `A` is `inline-block` so its `height` is for example `x`. when you make it `block` it should fill its parent, but, in `IE` mind, its parent has `width:0`. so you should remove the first `inline-block` attribute from `div.ib a` **OR** you can create a *fixed-width* attribute for floated `div` element.

```
div { float: left; margin: 5px; width: 80px; }
```

also, insofar as I know, **W3C** recommends that *floated elements should have a fixed-width*. - ***IE 6* needs a fixed height too to work correctly!!!**

The another way -*if you can and your solution allows you*- is that change the first `inline-block` to `inline` just for `IE`:

```
display: inline-block; 
*display: inline;
```

But the `width` solution (for `div`) is more standard and flexible.

**END UPDATE**

However, for overriding a `css-attribute` just in `IE`, you have 3 optional way to do:

1. The first way is using *conditional comment* that makes it's content visible to `IE` only. A full example is something like this:

   ```
   <!-- visible to IE less that 7 (6, 5, etc) -->
   <!--[if lt IE 7]> <link href="/Content/ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <![endif]-->

   <!-- visible to IE 7 only -->
   <!--[if IE 7]> <link href="/Content/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <![endif]-->

   <!-- visible to IE 8 only -->
   <!--[if IE 8]> <link href="/Content/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <![endif]-->

   <!-- visible to IE 9 and above and also visible to other browsers -->
   <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <link href="/Content/normal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <!--<![endif]-->
   ```

   As you can see, you have many options to use *conditional comment*.
2. The other way is using `CSS` specially selectors that make some selectors visible to `IE` and hide them from other browsers. A full example is:

   ```
   /* normal */
   your-selector{
   }

   /* visible to IE 6 only */
   * html your-selector{
   }

   /* visible to IE 7  only */
   *:first-child + html your-selector{
   }

   /* visible to IE 7 and above */
   html > body your-selector{
   }

   /* visible to IE 8 and above */
   html > /**/ body your-selector{
   }
   ```
3. The third way that I know is using `IE` specialized css-properties:

   ```
   /* normal selector */
   your-selector{
       /* normal property, visible to all browsers */
       color: #FF0;
       padding: 20px auto 35px;

       /* use special properties in name/value for IE */

       /* visible to ie 6 only */
       _color: #FF0;
       _padding: 15px auto 30px;

       /* visible to ie 7 and below (7, 6, 5, ...) */
       *color:#FF0;
       *padding: 15px auto 30px;
   }
   ```

---

Let me know if you have any questions or need clarifications on any part.

Comment: +1 for a complete answer on how to apply browser-specific styles. However, have you actually tried applying any of these to my example? GolezTrol basically suggested strategy 1, and you can see the results of that effort in my comments on his post.

Comment: I'm amazed this has as many upvotes as it does, considering it does not address the actual issue (of course, I commend the questioner for upvoting it despite the fact that it did not address his issue).

Comment: @StriplingWarrior In fact I cant understand your issue, I just understand you want to override some styles in `IE`, so my solution explains it -my English in not good enough, so sorry-. If you can, please upload a screenshot of FF rendered page and another from `IE`, then, I can help you to correct the problem in IE

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I can understand your issue just now :D the problem is on `div` floating. When you float an element, that will be outside of pages normal stream, so, `IE` will take for it `width:0; height:0;` and when you put in it some elements, they will create their own `height` and `width` and the `floated-element` will be rendered how can push them (my English is really bad, so sorry). First step, `A` is `inline-block` so it `height` is for example `x`. when you make it `block` it should fill its parent, but, in `IE` mind, its parent has width `0`! (continue in next comment)

Comment: you should remove the first `inline-block` attribute from `div.ib a` **OR** you can create a fixed-width attribute for floated `dev` element. `div {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px; width: 80px;
}` also, insofar as I know, W3C recommends that floated elements should have a fixed-width. -*`IE 6`* needs a fixed height too to work correctly!!!-.

Comment: The another way -if you can and your solution allows you- is that change the first `inline-block` to `inline` just for `IE`: `display: inline-block; *display: inline;` But the `width` solution (for `div`) is more standard and flexible. Regards

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation. Since my DIV has different links in it depending on context, I'm hoping to find a solution that allows the width of all the links to match the width of the widest link, the way it does in all decent browsers. :-S I may just have to restructure things so the `ib` class doesn't get added to those links in the first place. (In my real example, the class is on the links, not the div, and it applies a variety of other styles that I was hoping not to have to duplicate).

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I hope you can find the best solution. But just for an option, you can use JavaScript. In fact I use jQuery to solve these kind of problems, jQuery is flexible and cross-browser. Test and taste it if you don't yet. Best regards

Comment: You should update your answer to reflect to what is in the comments. The answer is not-so-good whereas the comments actually describe the real problem.

Comment: @Scott Do you have literacy? And can you read really? If yep so please read the answers and my comments!

Comment: Yes, I can read. Your comment on Nov 21 21:02 is stating the same thing my answer stated, posted at 19:11 and updated as of 20:33. Your comment on Nov 21 21:18 states the original answer that Galled posted on Nov 20 22:48.

Comment: Oops!!!!!! Please read again about your answer. and about Galled s answer, why you think if Galled knows anything, there is no one that knows it too?!!!!!!!

Comment: It is not that you might not know it too, it is that since Galled posted the answer prior to you, you should have just upvoted it.

Comment: OK, Galled posted `*display:` at `22:48` and I posted my own at `22:40`! Also I describe to starter first time I couldnt understand the Q correctly also if you read some of my posts you'l see I have no problem via html/css! Do you need I provide you some web-sites link I do them? However if you are so sad and angry I can delete my post Its not so important for me. Also, starter ask me in comments and I answer him in comments too! If your or Galled answers was helpful why he asked me? That's might you and Galled follow my comments and update your answer to complete it

Comment: I am neither sad nor angry, and you need not delete your post. I'm sure your html/css skills are great. I was only pointing out that you please be aware of other answers and upvote if you agree rather than change your own answer to one already offered. Your `original` answer was at `Nov 20th 22:40` (which did not answer the question, it only showed targeting IE), but you admit your understanding of the question was not until `Nov 21st 20:56` ("I can understand your issue just now"), almost a whole day after Galled's `*display` answer. Just be aware and give credit, that's all. No bad feelings.

Answer (score 4):

Acording with this [article](http://www.brunildo.org/test/InlineBlockLayout.html) `display:inline-block` has a similar behavior that `display:inline` in IE7, so you can make a litte change only to support IE7 (with a [simple hack for IE](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/)):

```
div.ib a {
   display: inline-block; 
   *display: inline; /* IE7 and below */ 
}
```

I hope [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mmpX3/12/) works as you expected.

---

**EDIT:**

Ok. The problem are with the property hasLayout explaining [here](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html#def). Both `zoom:1` and `height:any_value` activates the hasLayout, so meanwhile `display:inline-block; *display:inline` works to overwrite the next `display:block` declarations, putting a `height:30px` (for example) returns the property hasLayout. So the thing to do is remove the hasLayout as it says in [this article](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html#reset).

I have [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mmpX3/57/) to show how works. Because `height` is practically untouchable I using `padding-bottom` and `font-size` to simulate the `height` in other browsers. Note that the `width` of the widest element is maintained.

---

**EDIT2:**

Have you are considerate [jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/mmpX3/76/) solutions? (Only giving the elements different `width`s in IE7)

Comment: This does appear to enable IE7 to override the `block` attribute, but unfortunately it also makes it so that elements in `ib` divs without the `blockbyclass` applied will appear as `inline`. As I stated in the original question, "I have a certain type of link that under most circumstances needs to be rendered as inline-block." I need CSS styles like `height` to be applied, and those styles are ignored by `inline` elements.

Comment: Just going to ask you whether it was necessary that the attribute `display:inline-block` must be exactly explicit or it can be simulated in other way.

Comment: I would be fine with `inline-block` being simulated by some other means, as long as the behavior is the same. In the demo given in your updated answer, the `height: 30px` is not applied because the `*display: inline` makes IE7 ignore the height value.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I updated again, `height:30px` practically always cannot be applicable in IE7, and not because `*display:inline` since that after I applied `display:block`. Is for `hasLayout` and the only way I see to simulate the `height` is through `padding`.

Comment: +1 for outside-the-box thinking. Never would have thought of using jQuery for this. Not sure I want to. But it's a clever idea.

Comment: I'm awarding you the bounty for coming up with the jQuery solution, which is really the only answer that appears to do what I was asking for. I'm marking Scott's answer correct because he correctly explained that `hasLayout` can't really be reset, and his workaround is probably the approach I'll end up using. Thanks for your effort in helping me solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can put styles for IE7 in a separate CSS and use a [conditional comment](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to include it only for IE7.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link ...your IE7 specific stylesheet goes here ... >
<![endif]-->
```

Make sure this piece of code is below the link to the regular css file.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how I can use this technique in this specific case? I need the links to appear as inline-block elements in most cases, regardless of the user's browser. But I need to override that behavior in this one particular part of the page.

Comment: Then you have to make a specific selector for them. If that part is inside a div with a specific class, you could do somethgin like `div.ib.blockbyclass a { /* Matches all links inside the second div */ }`. But that's just standard CSS rules. I would get rid of the inline style attribute you're using now. That is bound to give you problems.

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/StriplingWarrior/UBxhV/ It still doesn't work. My problem is not with finding CSS selectors that will apply the styles I want. As I state in the original post, the problem is that IE7 refuses to make the new style truly override the old one.

Comment: It will if you follow my instructions. Put the override for IE7 in a separate CSS file, and link to it from within a conditional comment. That causes IE 7 to load that file, while every other browsers leaves it alone. You can set some other, more obvious styles to, to check if the file is indeed loaded. Also not that IE (just like Chrome) has a quite thorough caching, so it may have cached a previous/older version of your css.

Comment: I couldn't do that with jsfiddle, but I just did everything you said using local files on my hard drive, and I get exactly the same results in IE7 (of course, this breaks things for the other browsers because they no longer load the special override style). The thing is, I'm not trying to make IE7 behave differently from other browsers: I'm trying to make it behave the same as the other browsers. Even though all the CSS precedence rules say my `block` style needs to override the `inline-block` style, IE7 still renders the links as `inline-block`.

Comment: Can you just put the stuff online in a real site? That's easier that jsfiddle in this case.

Comment: Haven't got IE7, so I tested it in IE6 (changing the 7 to 6 in the conditional comment). Apparently the direct-child selector messes things up. If I change `div.ib.blockbyclass > a` to `div.ib.blockbyclass a`, it works. Now I think that this operator should work in both IE6 and 7, but maybe it applies some other precedence rules.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't have any effect on IE7 (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1410398/stackoverflow/8057233/2/test.htm). This issue is also reproducible on IE9 if you use the developer tools to set the Browser and Document modes to IE7 and "IE7 standards" respectively. The developer tools indicate that the precedence is being applied correctly. Nevertheless, it's obviously not behaving the same way as when the "ib" rule is not present.

Answer (score 1):

```
display: inline-block
```

for IE7 looks like:

```
*display: inline;
zoom: 1
```

Comment: I've used that trick to convince block-level elements (like `div`s) to act like `inline-block` elements. Unfortunately, it appears to behave the same as `display: inline-block` when applied to links. http://jsfiddle.net/mmpX3/18/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mmpX3/50/ look in IE 7. you CAN set height to this link (*display: inline)

Comment: Yes, this allows you to set the height, but now the link doesn't extend to take up all the space it's given, like a `block` element should do.

Comment: in your example all elements have display:block. display: inline-block element never take all width: http://jsfiddle.net/mmpX3/65/

Comment: Closer, but if my anchors have a height on them, it suddenly doesn't work again. http://jsfiddle.net/mmpX3/77/ :-(

Comment: look like IE bug. you need to set width to float element: http://jsfiddle.net/mmpX3/122/

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline-block` is not compatible in IE7 for elements which are not inline by default so IE will ignore this rule for DIVs.  If you change the DIV to a SPAN for example then this example should work.

Comment: The `display: inline-block;` is on the links, not the divs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing: If you need the `a` tag anchors to render on their own lines, they are block elements, not inline... In fact, there's nothing about what you're saying that indicates a need for an inline-block. Your `divs` are floating, so they'll stack to the left, in a line (but not inline; they are outside the flow of the document, thus `float`).

Try this... let's strip it all down. Here's the HTML you gave us:

```
<div class="normal">
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">Test longer</a>
</div>
<div class="ib blockbyclass">
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">Test longer</a>
</div>
<div class="ib">
    <a href="#" style="display: block;">Test</a>
    <a href="#" style="display: block;">Test longer</a>
</div>
```

With the CSS you provided, in Safari and Firefox, I see three blocks with two links each, each on their own line. What you're seeing in IE7, however, isn't two `inline-block` elements, but just two `inline` elements – the reason for this is that `inline-block` is not supported in IE7 because of a `hasLayout` error (something Microsoft created to overcomplicate a simple issue). In other words, it can't forget `inline-block` because it simply doesn't understand `inline-block` (which you've misunderstood as necessary), and is treating `a` by its default display behavior (i.e. `inline`).

If they need to be on separate lines and take up the width of the container, all you have to do is this (demonstrated on `.ib a`, completely ignoring `blockbyclass` which seems to just be a red herring in this case):

```
.ib a {display:block;}
```

TADA! Width is inherited from the parent container, the `a` takes the default `a` stylings, and everything is happy. So take a look at this:

```
<div class="ib">
    <a href="#" style="display: block;">Test</a>
    <a href="#" style="display: block;">Test longer</a>
</div>
```

This, in this case, becomes redundant, and therefore unnecessary. You're already making those elements block.

```
<div class="ib">
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">Test longer</a>
</div>
```

You're simply overcomplicating something really very simple.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dhYjZ/1/

Comment: The `ib` class was intended to simulate the class that I use system-wide for buttons, which applies `inline-block` because they normally have to be able to appear inline with each other, but still have block-oriented properties like height and margin applied. I was hoping I could override the `ib` class to make these buttons appear in `block` form in a specific case (the way the example works in all other browsers), but it sounds like `hasLayout` is going to make this impossible for me to do in IE7. I'll probably have to create another class that clones `ib`, but with `block` layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what is the end-result that you are after. Are you trying to make the black background to be a whole rectangle that encapsulates both links instead of 2 rectangles (1 for each link)?

If so, why not apply the background to the `DIV` instead of the links?

EDIT:
It seems that there's a bug with IE7 that makes it display elements in a mixture of `block` and `inline-block` when one of the rules that applies to the element has `display: inline-block` even if another value for `display` takes precedence.

If you see http://jsfiddle.net/P2N5c/16/ , it doesn't matter if the rule that has `display: block` is the first one (like the one using the `#blocky` rule) or if it's the last one.

So far I'm not sure how to prevent this bug, but you could bypass it by avoid giving the links both `ib` and `blockbyclass` and just giving it the classes that make them blocks. I.e. don't give them `ib`. Instead of adding a class to toggle the states for the DIV, replace one class for the other.

Comment: For future reference, clarifying questions should generally be posted as comments instead of answers. I'm trying to make all of the buttons take up as much space as the longest button in the list, so if you click anywhere within the button area it will have the same effect as clicking on the text.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Yesterday I didn't have commenting priviledges. One more clarification, you mention you have a DIV with just `ib` and then also get a DIV with both `ib blockbyclass`. Is `blockbyclass` added with script or is it there when the page loads?

Oh I get it, the anchors get the newline but fail to grab the whole width (in IE7).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `float` is to blame here. It is not that IE7 does not mark the item as `block`, I think it is due to the `div` `float` not having a width. This can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mmpX3/129/

Typically, when working with older browsers, I have found that floated elements in <= IE7 tend to need a fixed width setting to avoid issues.

In your case, I would suggest adding a fixed width as the JS Fiddle, or remove the `float` if it is not needed. If I can see the use case for the floated `div`, I may be able to come up with an alternative.

Why a combination of `float` and `display:inline-block` stops `display:block` from being re-instanted, I don't know. It sounds like a typical IE7 bug that can be worked around.

Answer (score -1):

Simply put, I replace all of my `display:inline-block;` usages with `display:inline;`, and I also do so conditionally, as with the answers provided above.

With your example, I find success with the following:

```
body{background-color: gray;}
div{float:left; margin: 5px;}
a {background-color: black; color: white;display:block;}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zL3Ea/

Comment: May I enquire... why the minus? The code above makes the links inside the floated divs because blockish in all of your specified browsers.

Comment: For the record: I'm not the one who -1'd you. However, I'm confused at the difference between what you explain in your first paragraph and what you actually do in your posted code. The code doesn't have any `display:inline;` in it, or any conditional selectors. Was that just an oversight?

Comment: Sorry, it was just more of a general approach to handling display:inline-block; for IE7. The second part should be the juiciest.

Comment: The second part just gets rid of the inline-block directive that I need to have applied whenever my `blockbyclass` class is not present. I'm afraid that's not really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like jobs done.
I am fork your code, try it: http://jsfiddle.net/Lkwzx/1/

Secret in this line: `div.ib a { display: inline-block; *display: inline; }`

Comment: For the record, I didn't downvote this. But it is the same as Galled's answer, and like his it does not make `ib` links have `inline-block` applied when `blockbyclass` is not present.